# Create Shortcut for exe located in sub directory of INSTALLDIR and using HarvestDirectory

Tags: wix, wix4

I am creating MSI using Wix 4.0 command line tools.

I came across a requirement where I want to create shortcut with pointing target exe located in sub folder of INSTALLDIR.
My directory structure is as below:
INSTALLDIR -> C:\Program Files\AppCheck
Folder Structure of

```
AppCheck
-AppSecure
-Somefile.dll
-Somefile4.xml
-AppBlock
    =Block.exe
-AppScan-Somefile2.dll-Somefile3.json
-AppSet   
    =AppSet.exe
```

I need to create shortcuts for Block.exe and AppSet.exe
I have created Apps.wsx file as below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" Name="ApplicationName" Version="1.0.0" Manufacturer="MyCompany" Language="en-US">
    
        <Package InstallerVersion="300" Compressed="yes" Manufacturer="Me" Keywords="Installer,MSI,Database" Comments="This installer database contains the logic and data required to install application" InstallPrivileges="limited"/>
        <Media Id="1" Cabinet="ApplicationName.cab" EmbedCab="yes" CompressionLevel="mszip"/>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            
            <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
            </Directory>
        </Directory>

        <DirectoryRef Id=" ProgramMenuFolder">
            <Component Id="ApplicationShortcut" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE">
                <Shortcut Id="AppSet" 
                  Name="AppSet"
                  Description="AppSet"
                  Target="[#appset.exe]"
                  WorkingDirectory="TARGETDIR"/>
                <Shortcut Id="Block" 
                  Name="Block"
                  Description="block"
                  Target="[#block.exe]"
                  WorkingDirectory="TARGETDIR"/>
        </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>

        <ItemGroup>
            <HarvestDirectory Include="C://Temp//AppCheck" KeepEmptyDirectories="true" DirectoryRefId=" TARGETDIR " HarvestDirectoryKeepEmptyDirectories="">
                
            </HarvestDirectory>
        </ItemGroup>
        
    </Product>
</Wix>
```

When I am creating msi shortcut getting created with TARGETDIR/INSTALLDIR as working directory instead of subfolder name appscan and appsecure.
Is any option or approach available in Wix 4 to use directory path of subfolder in working directory attribute of shortcut?

Thank you in advance!!!